# Volume of solid by integration

Tags: integration, geometry, area

> A solid lies between planes perpendicular to the x-axis at $x=0$ and $x=18$. The cross sections perpendicular to the axis on the interval $0 \le x \le 18$ are squares with diagonals that run from the parabola $y= -2 \sqrt{x}$ to the parabola $y=2 \sqrt{x}$. Find the volume of the solid

I found the length of the square: $L = 2 \sqrt{x}  - (-2 \sqrt{x}) = 4 \sqrt{x}$

To find volume, I need to integrate the area of the cross section.

Since the cross section is square, Area is $A(x) = L^2$

but I'm wrong, the $A(X) = \frac{L^2}{2}$

Why do I have to divide by 2 for the cross section which is a square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that the *diagonal* of the square lies between those points, not the *side* as you have found. Note if square has side $s$, by the Pythagorean Theorem, its diagonal is $d = s\sqrt{2}$. Hence,
$$
A = s^2 = \left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = \frac{d^2}{2}
$$